# Writing a centered distribution function as $F(x)=\iint \frac{w } {u+w }1_{[u,w) }(x)+1_{([w,\infty)}(x) \nu(du,dw) $

Tags: probability-theory

I'm asked to write a centered distribution function $F(x) $ ( centered meaning that $\int x dF(x)=0 $ ) as $$F(x)=\iint \frac{w } {u+w }1_{[u,w) }(x)+1_{([w,\infty)}(x) \nu(du,dw) $$ where $\nu(du,dw)=\frac {1 }{\alpha } (w-u)1_{u \le 0 \le w }(u,v)dF(u)dF(w)$

*I'm trying to motivate two things. 1) That the introduced measure $\nu $ really is a measure and 2) the equivalence of the distribution function $F $ with the repeted integral of the point mass distrubution function w.r.t. the introduced measure $\nu $.*

For 1)

Since $\frac{w } {u+w }1_{[u,w) }(x)+1_{([w,\infty)}(x) $ is the distribution function of the point mass $\frac{w } {u+w }\delta _u + \frac{u } {u+w }\delta_w$ the above then is some kind of average (integral) of point mass distributions.

If we put $\nu(du,dw)=\frac {1 } {\alpha } (w-u)1_{u \le 0 \le w }(u,w)dF(u)dF(w)$ how do we motivate this is a measure? I believe $dF(u)dF(w)$ corresponds to the usual product measure of $P_X $ with itself, where $P_X $ is the probability measure corresponding to $F $. What do we get when we multiply this with $1_{u \le 0 \le w }(u,w) $? Is it equivalent to concentrating $P_x \otimes P_X $ on the second quandrant by defining a new measure on $R^2 $, $\mu(A) = P_X \otimes P_X(A \cap B )$ where $B=\{(x,y):x \le 0 \le y \} $?

For 2)

In my calculations I would like to claim that

$$
\iint_{u \le 0 \le w } w1_{[u,\infty)}(x)-u1_{([w,\infty)}(x)dF(u)dF(w) 
\\= \iint_{u \le 0 \le w } w1_{(-\infty,x]}(u)-u1_{((-\infty,x]}(w)dF(u)dF(w)
$$

And I'm not sure how to motivate, even tough I can see that $x \in [u,\infty ) \iff u \in (-\infty ,x]$. The rest of the verification I'm able to do so you don't have to supply it!

Many thanks in advance!